# Using Android 2.2 Datepicking dialog in android 3.2

Tags: android

Is it possible to use 2.2's datepicker dialog in 3.2 android? I need this because datapicker dialog in 3.2 has one calendar and one datepicking box together which makes it too big and unefficient to use. Its very useful in 2.2 because it just have datepicking box.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need this because datapicker dialog in 3.2 has one calendar and one datepicking box together which makes it too big and unefficient to use.

This is your opinion. Your opinion does not matter. The opinions of your users matter. Your users may appreciate being able to pop up a calendar view. Bear in mind that Android 3.2 is for tablets, with 7" diagonal screens or larger, and so your users may not find that the dialog is "too big and unefficient to use".

> Is it possible to use 2.2's datepicker dialog in 3.2 android?

Grab the source code for it, refactor it into your own package (e.g., `com.mtu.something`), and use it.